# Cisco SF95D-08 switch config

Tags: networking, switch

I bought a Cisco SF95D-08 switch, but it seems that all of them are RJ45 Ethernet ports.

Does it mean that I cannot configure the switch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an unmanaged switch, so there is nothing to configure.

No vlans, no routing.